# Encapsulate text with quotes in a comma-separated file

Tags: php, list, csv, encapsulation

I have a CSV-file looking like this:

```
Amebiasis,California,2001,Total,571,34514777,1.654,1.521,1.796
Amebiasis,California,2001,Female,176,17340743,1.015,0.871,1.176
Amebiasis,California,2001,Male,365,17174034,2.125,1.913,2.355
```

I need a script which encapsulate all text blocks which makes it looks like:

```
"Amebiasis","California",2001,"Total",571,34514777,1.654,1.521,1.796
"Amebiasis","California",2001,"Female",176,17340743,1.015,0.871,1.176
"Amebiasis","California",2001,"Male",365,17174034,2.125,1.913,2.355
```

I'm used to work with PHP, but solutions in other languages are welcomed.

I tried to use Excel's native solutions, but that gives me three quotation marks:

```
    """Amebiasis""","""California""",2001,"""Total""",571,34514777,1.654,1.521,1.796
```

Comment: When Excel puts three double quotes its usually because the first and third are escaping the second - what exactly are you doing when using 'Excels native solution'? I see no double quotes in your CSV to require escaping. see point 6 of http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180#section-2

Comment: - Edit the cell I need to format
- Choose format cell
- Select Custom from the bottom
- Use the formula \"@\"
- Save as CSV, comma-delimited.

Comment: The mystery double quotes are being inserted when you use \"@\" and then escaped once Excel writes the CSV file - I'm guessing if you were to reopen your modified CSV with the triple quotes the cells will appear inside Excel with normaly quoted strings

Answer (score 2):

You can use php native csv encoding function, but you have to add a small helper function. Reason is that the native function sticks with the `csv` standard which does *not* require cells to be enclosed if not required for parsing by their content structure.

This is an example:

```
<?php
function encodeFunc($value) { return "\"$value\""; }

$h_input = fopen('input.csv', 'r');
$h_output = fopen('output.csv', 'w');
while ($input = fgetcsv($h_input)) {
  fputcsv($h_output, array_map('encodeFunc', $input), ',', chr(0));
}
readfile('output.csv');
```

File `input.csv` does hold:

```
Amebiasis,California,2001,Total,571,34514777,1.654,1.521,1.796
Amebiasis,California,2001,Female,176,17340743,1.015,0.871,1.176
Amebiasis,California,2001,Male,365,17174034,2.125,1.913,2.355
```

File `output.csv` will hold:

```
"Amebiasis","California","2001","Total","571","34514777","1.654","1.521","1.796"
"Amebiasis","California","2001","Female","176","17340743","1.015","0.871","1.176"
"Amebiasis","California","2001","Male","365","17174034","2.125","1.913","2.355"
```

BTW: this approach works for large files too, it scales without problem, since it never loads the full file into memory but only a single row at a time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would say: *don't fix it if it ain't broke*. Your csv is perfect as it is.

But perhaps you need them to be quoted for certain software?

In general: in csv, quotes are not used to indicate that certain fields are text, but to escape delimiters (or newlines) inside fields, for example:

```
text1,"text2, some more",1.234,"44,25"
```

If you get 3 quotation marks using Excel, this means that the fields were already quoted, escaped with another quote and then surrounded with quotes (as @norlesh already mentioned).

```
"""Amebiasis""","""California"""
```

Whatever you do, don't use regex to '*fix*' csv, because that might break future updates of your data if fields have a seperator or quotes inside them.

Comment: But I really don't have any quotes in the file I'm using.
Otherwise there wouldn't be any problem.

I can't find anything when i search the excel file for ' " ' 
Whether I search within Excel or open the file with a text editor.

Comment: @AdamDedanga - Yes, that's what I understood. But why do you need to add quotes to the fields? As for _Excel's native solutions_, what do you mean with that? There must have been a quote somewhere in order to get 3 back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex and [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to modify it.

```js
$string = 'Amebiasis,California,2001,Total,571,34514777,1.654,1.521,1.796';
// '\b' is a word boundary
$pattern = '/\b/i';
$replacement = '"';
$newstring =  preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
//the string with quotes
echo $newstring;
```